# LDAP AUTHENTICATION UBUNTU

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openldap

I have setup an ldap server on Ubuntu,

Configuration steps:

```
sudo apt-get install slapd ldap-utils
```

Reconfigure LDAP

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure slapd
```

DNS name

```
example.com
```

Install PHPldapadmin

```
sudo apt-get install phpldapadmin
```

Open the configuration file with root privileges:

```
sudo nano /etc/phpldapadmin/config.php
```

server setvalues have been changed.

```
$servers->setValue
```

saved and closed.

When I load, in my browser, the URL  http://my own ip/phpldapadmin

I get the following error: Nginx: 404 not found.

```
sudo nano /etc/phpldapadmin/config.php
```

Comment: It looks like incorrect webserver setup, but you haven't posted it's settings.

Comment: I am new to it. If you don't mind which settings you are talking about..?

Comment: I'm talking about nginx settings. I think, it's one or more files somewhere under `/etc/nginx`. Visit their docs at http://wiki.nginx.org to get familiar with it. Pay attention to parts about setting up PHP apps.